# I am unable to filter by 'Name' in SharePoint picture library

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am rendering to a page blog posts.  Unfortunately, when the blog was initially set up, the pictures corresponding to each blog post was kept in a picture library for some odd reason. Now I need to dynamically display the appropriate picture with the correct blog post but I am having a hard time.  I am using SharePoint 2016 and using REST API to query the picture library.  I am able to query the library but I am not able to filter for a specific picture.

So, here's what I have,
the below works and shows the field that I need, **Name**

`/blog/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('blogPics')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File`

the below filtering doesn't work

`/blog/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('blogPics')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File&$filter=Name eq 'imgName.jpg'`

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use FileLeafRef to filter the specific picture.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('blogPics')/items?$select=FileRef,FileLeafRef&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'imgName.jpg'
```